# Question about undirected graph implementations

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm working on a C++ class that represents a simple undirected graph. I know it's not that complicated as there is plenty of tutorials on the web. I can't decide however if graph class methods should be called by vertex index or by vertex data.

```
template<class V, class E>
class SimpleGraphByIndex {
public:
    /// Adds vertex to this graph, return its index
    size_t add_vertex(V v);

    /// connect vertexes by indexes
    size_t add_edge(size_t i, size_t j, E e);

    bool are_connected(size_t i, size_t j) const;

    E & get_edge(size_t i, size_t j);

    const std::vector<size_t> & neighbors(size_t i) const;
}

template<class V, class E>
class SimpleGraphByData {
public:
    /// Adds vertex to this graph, return its index
    bool add_vertex(V v);

    /// connect given vertexes 
    size_t add_edge(const V & vi, const V & vj, E e);

    bool are_connected(const V & vi, const V & vj);

    E & get_edge(const V & vi, const V & vj);

    const std::vector<V> & neighbors(const V & vi) const;
private:
    size_t get_index(const V & vi) const;
}
```

I have to store both V and E data for my graph (i.e. there are different kinds of edges) and I use list-of-neighbors implementation that internally stores indexes of connected vertexes for each node.

Is it OK to expose internal indexing of graph nodes? In my application indexes related to V data are known, e.g. it's a field of the V class (but it's unknown to SimpleGraph type). When SimpleGraph keeps track of indexing, it needs to keep an std::map and retrieve the indexes in log(N) time. I store up to several thousands nodes, typically a few hundreds of them.

Or maybe I should provide both interfaces in my class i.e. to allow access both by data and index?

Comment: Indices allow for pretty quick and efficient access if you store the vertices inside a *private* std::vector, but they can easily get mixed up from outside. The by value-approach is less efficient (you need to find the elements inside the vector), but is safer. With indices, you *could* allow to insert duplicate vertices (doesn't appear meaningful, though), by value, you cannot identify a specific duplicate and might get indeterminate results...

Comment: A bit in doubt of the design, though. Storing a list of all the vertices that are reachable from a specific one directly in the vertex appears more natural to me.